# Trapezoidal Map and Search Tree

Tags: complexity-theory, data-structures, computational-geometry, search-trees

i am studying on trapezoidal maps. In the last section, "Analysis" of [this paper](http://cglab.ca/%7Ecdillaba/comp5008/mulmuley.html), it says "The expected query time is indeed O(log n). Again the search structure size can be quadratic in the worst case, but the expected size is O(n)."

Here is what i did not understand well. How it is possible to reach a quadratic size of search structure? For example, if i insert all the segments one by one in a specific order and let their number is 5(5 segments and 10 vertices normally). So there are two possible cases. One is: "The edge falls entirely within an old trapezoid" and the second one is : "The edge crosses over at least one old extension". To understand better i tried to divide the plane into two slabs and realized that the number of the slabs are not the quadratic to the number of segments. What i mean is i expected that if i have 5 segments than i have to have 20 slabs and so the search structure would be quadratic to number of segments either.

Finally, can anyone show that if there exists any set of segments which may yield a search structure which is quadratic with number of segments? If it is possible, is it related with the insertion order?  For my opinion it is directly related with the order of segments.